# Problem with data collection in tables

Tags: php, apache

I have the following to do. I am migrating web content from a joomla to a WordPress, and the problem that I present is that the joomla has a collection of data in tables that is not compatible with WordPress, when I use the wordpress hook

`wp_insert_post`

It does not save the field with the data that I need to convert to another collection to be able to save them with their respective accents.

I hope you understand me.

I have the following

```php
$id = wp_insert_post(array(
‘post_title’ => utf8_encode($hello[‘title’]),
‘post_content’ => utf8_encode($metadesc.’ ‘.$hello[‘fulltext’]),
‘post_date’ => $hello[‘created’],
'post_author' => '1',
'post_type'=>'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'comment_status' => 'open',
‘post_name’ => utf8_decode($hello[‘alias’]),
));
```

`post_content` is where I need to save the information with my respective tildes.

But it doesn't save them, the result is blank, the operation doesn't return anything, and the apache or php log doesn't tell me anything.

the data comes with this collection `utf8_general_ci` and in wordpress it is in `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`

Try to do it with Laravel by hand, but it's the same.

I can show the information on the web with their respective accents, but I need to save it in the database with accents and others.

I hope you can give me an idea of ​​what to investigate about it

Cheers

Comment: I edited your question so the code block is formatted as code, but there's no context, the code examples are incomplete, and you're mixing up the names of things making it confusing ( a hook is not a function ). I also do not understand why you'r UTF8 encoding and decoding, this is unnecessary. What is an accent? Are you referring to àáâäæ? The code that generates `$hello` is missing, and there are syntax errors in the code quotes. Please use the `Edit` link to update your question

Comment: The problem is that the data is typically saved t&iacute;pico like this in the database when they have a tilde or some sign.

Comment: it's very likely that the content is already HTML encoded _before_ it reaches the code in your question, and that the issue has nothing to do with UTF encoding because those are HTML entities. Your `utf8_encode` calls are probably making it worse. `wp_insert_post` is not the source of your problem, and your UTF encoding theory is incorrect